# How do I report an incorrect privilege notification

Tags: bug

I posted an answer yesterday which earned +10 points, taking me to 41.

The little "Trophy" icon (3rd to left in the top right) is telling me

*"You've earned the "comment everywhere" privilege!

Learn more about it in the help center.*

However the rest of the system says (correctly) I get that at 50.

The Trophy icon goes across multiple stackexchanges but the notice is clearly for (and maybe from) Unix & Linux (it's got the "UL").

Comment: My best guess is that someone had temporarily up-voted one of your answers, during which the privilege was awarded, and they later retracted their up-vote. I don't have any evidence behind this assumption at all, though!

Comment: @JeffSchaller I also don't see any evidence of that.  Tell you what, upvote this question, then wait a minute or two, then retract that, and we'll see if I get another notice.

Comment: @DarkMatter upvotes on meta don't give rep

Comment: The main meta site has this covered as well - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/154830/why-arent-awarded-badges-removed-if-the-question-is-deleted/154832#154832.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Jeff is correct: someone upvoted or accepted one of your posts, and then it was retracted within the grace period. The evidence is that [the reputation tab of your activity](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/190964/dark-matter?tab=reputation) says:

> There were no net reputation changes on this day.

[This message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129067/270345) is only seen when some event that would have caused a reputation change and an entry in this tab had happened, but was undone.